# Writing a Win32 Application with C++11

Tags: c++, winapi, c++11

I asked myself these days about how to write Win32 GUI applications in pure C++11. As I see, the Visual Studio Win32 GUI template creates code that uses C. (FOR EXAMPLE: )

```
HINSTANCE hInst;                        
TCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];
TCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];
```

So my questions are as simple as follows:

1. **How to write a Win32 GUI Application in pure C++11?**
2. **What else should I use the be able to use only the C++11 standard containers and other things?**

Comment: That's valid C++. What's the problem? If you want to use standard library containers, just write it yourself.

Comment: @JosephMansfield, maybe my question is not correctly expressed, but I hope you know what I need. I know that `TCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING]` is a valid C++ container, but instead of it I would use, for example `std::wstring`. By `pure C++11`, I meant using the latest standard.

Comment: Again, what is the actual problem? Of course you can use STL containers like `std::string` and `std::wstring`. The Win32 API doesn't care how you allocate your buffers, only that they use the correct data type (`char` vs `wchar_t`, etc).

Comment: Well, 3 years late... but you may want to take a look at [WinLamb](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1184175/WinLamb-using-Cplusplus-lambdas-to-handle-Win-mess) library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the code that Visual Studio generates, don't use it.  But remember, win32 is a C API, so at some point you will have to convert those `std:wstring`s to C strings.

Comment: so instead of a Win32 Application, what I should use an MFC one?

Comment: To be honest I'd use something like Qt instead

Comment: You can use `std::string` and `std::wstring` with API functions, you would simply use the `c_str()` or `data()` methods to access the underlying memory blocks they allocate, and then pass those pointers to the API as needed.